# How do I read my date variable with gaps in R?

Tags: object, stock, zoo

I have a Daily dataset from April 2008 to January 2017 which includes macroeconomic variables as well as data on stock prices indices. I have gaps in my date variable, since the dataset includes stock prices which does not include data for Saturday and Sundays. When I am trying to make a ts object or Zoo object, R fails to take gaps in date variable.
Could anyone help me how to solve this issue in R? It would be great help for me.

I run the following codes to make a zoo object:

```
library(zoo)
date <- zooreg((1:nrow(dataset)), start= as.Date('2008-04-08'), end = as.Date('2017-01-31'))
data.zoo <- zoo(dataset[,2:ncol(dataset)], order.by=index(date))
```

After running these codes, if I plot my data, It shows from 2008 to 2014, as it fails to capture the gaps in date variable.

Comment: Hi Richa! Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is 10x more likely to get answered if you include sample data with your question. Would you be able to share some/all of your stock price data? You can use `dput(dataset)` to get it